AWS sensitive data showing in chunk vendor js file
I am using vuejs3 and Laravel. My AWS sensitive data is showing in chunk-vendor.js file.
I stored the all sensitive data in .env file and accessing all the keys through env variables but still it is showing in chunk-vendor.js file. if there is another way to prevent or hide the sensitive details

VueJS is client-side, hence the code will be publicly inspectable yes.
